# Codeception environments config in 2.1.1 (environment matrix)

Tags: environment, codeception

I am trying to run a test suite using configs from two environments (this is a feature implemented in 2.1 -  http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Environments) and when I run bin/codecept suite --env env1,env2 it just runs full resolution on chrome, which is the default setting in codeception.yml. Here is the contents of env1 and env2:

env2:

`modules:
    config:
        WebDriver:
            window_size: 320x450
            capabilities: []`

env1:

`modules:
    config:
        WebDriver:
            browser: 'firefox'`

env1.yml and env2.yml are correctly placed in the _envs forlder, and the path to this folder is specified in codeception.yml.

The yml of the suite I am trying to run is:

`class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Acceptance
        - WebDriver`

This is codeception.yml:

`actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    helpers: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Acceptance
        - WebDriver
    config:
        WebDriver:
            url: 'http://myurl.com/'
            browser: 'chrome'
            host: 127.0.0.1
            port: 4444
            window_size: 1920x1080`

Answer (score 1):

you have to run it with the following, otherwise codeception combines the settings:

```
--env env1 --env env2
```